# windows authentication and allow roles base authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to implement C# asp.net application with windows authontication and allow roles base authorization.

So can anyone give me How to set the web.config file?

Thanks in Advance,
Rajesh

Comment: It's all controlled via the [authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/532aee0e(v=vs.85).aspx) / [authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d82143t(v=vs.85).aspx) elements (if using the web.config), just read the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

In web.config file you should change authentication mode to windows

```
 <system.web>
 ...
 <authentication mode="Windows"/>
 ...
 </system.web>
```

And in your web.config file of directory (will be in authenticated one), you should add;

```
 <authorization>
 <allow users="DomainName\Bob, DomainName\Mary" />
 <allow roles="BUILTIN\Administrators, DomainName\Manager" />
 <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

Domain name here is name of users who logged in a active directory.
Add a web.config file to the directory that you don't want to be seen by anonymous users. Then also you should enable role manager by adding this in root web.config file;

```
<system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
</system.web>
```

Here is a detailed doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d82143t(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: How\Where to create Roles?

Answer (score 0):

In the Web.config file, locate the  tag, and then set the mode attribute to Windows, as in the following example:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

In ASP.NET, you set authorization to the application by adding settings in the Web.config file. You can specify which users or groups are permitted to have access to what resources as follows:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="domainname\Managers" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Get Error Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's administrator for additional assistance.

Comment: Which IIS version you are using it seems that Windows Authentication was not installed by default with IIS version.

Comment: try this link:   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/253667

Comment: Using IIS 7.5.7600.16385

Comment: Windows Authentication was not installed by default with IIS7.

Comment: How can i install that on my machine

Comment: try this link  http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication

Comment: Windows Authentication is Enable in IIS7